# no icons using fontawesome npm in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I've installed fontawesome npm into my meteor app and I'm not able to to get the fontawesome icons to appear on the webpage. There's no error in my console so I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

Am I importing it in the wrong place?

Path: `imports/ui/layouts/body/body.js`

`import fontawesome from 'fontawesome';`

Comment: Did you add fontawesome package by cmd: meteor add fortawesome:fontawesome ?

Comment: No, I'm trying to move over to NPM packages. I ran `npm install fontawesome`

Comment: You should install that meteor package. Then meteor will import it to source automatically. Should also remove the previous npm one.

Comment: Doesn't meteor imply we should migrate away from atmosphere packages to NPM packages.

Comment: I have no idea. I prefer using atmosphere packages for client lib. If you use NPM package for server side, you need to use Npm.require().

Comment: Yep, I've gone with your original suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although the atmosphere library says to use npm.  I have spent quite a bit of time making the npm library work.  Both the less version and the normal css.  No luck sadly.

Use

```
Meteor add fortawesome:fontawesome
```

I'd love to use the npm package, but at this point continuing to use the atmosphere package is easier, working and has no apparent disadvantage to what I can tell.